# matplotlib wxPython backend crashing after large image stack processing

Tags: python, matplotlib, image-processing, wxpython, large-data

I got stuck with an wxAssertionError (shown below) when processing a large image stack. Let me explain with an example.

I have made an interface with wxPython with just a panel, a button and a gauge bar.

Once user clicks on the button, the code reads a stack of 8-bit binary images (1500 x 100 x 50), shows the first image on the panel and starts processing the stack. An example stack can be downloaded [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/hoy82c2pbv4qiz6/stack.tif?dl=0), click 'open->download' and put it in the same folder as the code below, please let me know in the comments if you can't get access to the stack). The processing step is a loop where each image from the stack is labeled and plotted in a figure (not in the panel). This figure is saved and closed in each iteraction. The code is shown below:

```
# Label and save big image stack
import wx
from matplotlib.backends.backend_wxagg import FigureCanvasWxAgg as FigureCanvas
from matplotlib.figure import Figure
class CanvasPanelA1(wx.Panel):
    def __init__(self, parent, ID):
        wx.Panel.__init__(self, parent, ID, style=wx.SUNKEN_BORDER)

        self.figure = Figure()
        self.figure.set_facecolor("BLACK")
        self.canvas = FigureCanvas(self, -1, self.figure)

        self.sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        self.sizer.Add(self.canvas, 1, wx.LEFT | wx.TOP | wx.EXPAND)
        self.SetSizer(self.sizer)
        self.Fit()

    def OnPlot(self, event):
        self.frame = frame
        from numpy import amin, amax
        self.vmin = amin(frame.video)
        self.vmax = amax(frame.video)
        self.nframes = frame.video.shape[0]
        self.axes = self.figure.add_subplot(111)
        self.axes.imshow(frame.video[0],cmap='gray',vmin=self.vmin,vmax=self.vmax)
        self.axes.axis('off')
        self.canvas.draw()
        self.SetSizer(self.sizer)
        frame.Layout()

class MyFrame(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, ID, title):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, parent, ID, title)
        self.panel = CanvasPanelA1(self, wx.ID_ANY)
        self.panel.SetMinSize((200,200))
        self.button_RUN = wx.Button(self, label="Run")
        self.gauge = wx.Gauge(self, range = 100, size = (250, 25), style = wx.GA_HORIZONTAL)
        mainSizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        mainSizer.Add(self.panel, 3, wx.EXPAND)

        mainSizer.Add(self.button_RUN,0,flag=wx.CENTER|wx.ALL)
        mainSizer.Add(self.gauge,0,flag=wx.CENTER|wx.EXPAND)
        self.button_RUN.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.OnRun)
        self.SetSizer(mainSizer)
        self.SetAutoLayout(True)
        self.Layout()
    def OnRun(self,event):
        from skimage.color import label2rgb 
        from skimage.measure import label
        import matplotlib as mpl
        import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
        from skimage import io
        from skimage.util import img_as_ubyte
        import os
        #read video
        video_name = './video1.tif'
        self.video = io.imread(video_name, as_gray=False, plugin='tifffile')
        self.video = img_as_ubyte(self.video)
        self.nframes = self.video.shape[0]
        self.gauge.SetRange(self.nframes-1)

        #show one image on panel
        self.panel.OnPlot(wx.EVT_DISPLAY_CHANGED)
        self.panel.Refresh()
        # Create Output Directory
        dirname = 'Outputs'
        try:
            os.mkdir(os.path.join('.',dirname))
            print("Directory " , dirname ,  " Created ") 
        except FileExistsError:
            print("Directory " , dirname ,  " already exists")

        plt.ioff()
        for fr in range(self.nframes):
            print('frame=',fr)
            label_image = label(self.video[fr], background=0) 
            image_label_overlay = label2rgb(label_image,bg_label=0)
            fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(10, 6))
            ax.imshow(image_label_overlay)
            plt.axis('off')
            imname = 'imgout'+str(fr).zfill(len(str(self.nframes)))+'.tif'
            output_path = os.path.join('.',dirname,imname)
            plt.savefig(output_path,bbox_inches='tight',facecolor='black',edgecolor='none')
            plt.close(fig)
            self.gauge.SetValue(fr)
        plt.ion()

app = wx.App()
frame = MyFrame(None, -1, "Label videos")
frame.Show()
app.MainLoop()
```

This code has worked so far with smaller stacks, but once I provide image stacks bigger than ~1250 frames, it gives the following error:

```
File "C:\Users\...\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\backends\backend_wx.py", line 1413, in _init_toolbar    
self.Realize()    
**wxAssertionError**: C++ assertion "Assert failure" failed at ..\..\src\msw\toolbar.cpp(938) in wxToolBar::Realize(): Could not add bitmap to toolbar
```

Since this error seems related to the toolbar and I do not use it, I have tried to disable it with `mpl.rcParams['toolbar'] = 'None'`, put before the loop, but then I get another AssertionError:

```
File "C:\Users\...\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\backends\backend_wx.py", line 1585, in __init__
self.SetFieldsCount(2)
**wxAssertionError**: C++ assertion "m_hdc" failed at ..\..\src\msw\textmeasure.cpp(64) in wxTextMeasure::BeginMeasuring(): Must not be used with non-native wxDCs
```

I have also tried using `wx.CallAfter(self.gauge.SetValue, fr)` as an attempt to avoid updating the main interface while plotting and saving the images, but it didn't work as well.

Does anyone have any idea of what is causing this?

Below are my packages version:
conda 4.4.1
python 3.6.8
wxPython 4.0.6
spyder 3.3.6
scikit-image 0.15.0   (edit: tried with latest version as well = 0.16.2, still no success)
matplotlib 3.1.1
numpy 1.16.4

Comment: Does it crash with a different backend too?

Comment: Yes. My spyder Ipython console is configured to use 'inline' backend at first, but once the code is run, the backend is changed to 'wxagg' in this line `self.canvas = FigureCanvas(self, -1, self.figure)`.
So now that you've mentioned it, I've tried to change the backend before the loop with `mpl.rcParams['backend'] = 'agg'`. I've tried with 'agg', 'cairo', 'qt5agg' and of course 'wxagg' as it was before. All of them gave the same previous error.

Comment: Did anyone try this? Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I think I solved it based on [this answer](http://matplotlib.1069221.n5.nabble.com/template/NamlServlet.jtp?macro=print_post&node=13367) to a similar problem.
It appears that one should not create a new figure inside the loop, even if one closes that figure inside the loop. My RAM was increasing after each loop iteration regardless of closing every new figure.

SOLUTION: create the figure instance before the loop. Then, plot inside the loop (save it if you want) and, instead of closing the figure, just clear it with `plt.clf()`. Only close the figure after the loop, as in the example below:

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(10, 6)) #create figure and axes
for fr in range(self.nframes):
    print('frame=',fr)
    label_image = label(self.video[fr], background=0) #some processing
    image_label_overlay = label2rgb(label_image,bg_label=0)   
    ax.imshow(image_label_overlay) #plot the image
    plt.axis('off')
    imname = 'imgout'+str(fr).zfill(len(str(self.nframes)))+'.tif'  
    output_path = os.path.join('.',dirname,imname)
    plt.savefig(output_path,bbox_inches='tight',facecolor='black',edgecolor='none') #save the figure
    self.gauge.SetValue(fr) #update gauge bar
    plt.clf() #clear current figure
plt.close(fig) #closes figure
```

Answer (score 0):

It's been 4 months since I posted this question and apparently nobody knows the answer.

I'd say there is some bug with matplotlib wxpython backends when processing a large amount of data.

Comment: This doesn't look like an answer. More of a guess.

Comment: You're probably right, let me dig into this problem a little furhter